# Rotate x axis text on Horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Is it possible to rotate x axis text when you got horizontal bar chart ? In the c3js documentation there is no example for this ?
[image]

If the chart is simple Bar chart without rotated: true property it works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rotated it, the x axis is now actually the y axis

so add this to your axis definition:

```
    y: {
        tick: {
            rotate: 45
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3943jwj/3/